# Iterate through dataframe and create new dataframe every time condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

From a SQL query I pull a list of activities that happen in the shop, one of the column has a label called 'STATUS'.

I want to go down the dataframe and pull the whole row every time the 'STATUS' label changes

- I've created a dataframe from the query and called it **df**
- Changed the column types to what I needed
- Created a list of all the column headers
- Used that list to create an empty dataframe to which I intended to append
- Tried creating a for loop with the condition described above

```py
    headerlist = df.columns.values.tolist() 

    newdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=headerlist)

    for index, row in df.iterrows():

        if df.STATUS[i] != df.STATUS[i-1]:
            newdf = newdf.append(i)
```

I've uploaded an image here that represents what I'm trying to achieve.

Thank you in advance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHpyD.jpg

Comment: can you give a runnable example ?

Comment: So you are iterating through a DataFrame and if the STATUS column in row n is different from row n-1 you want to append it to a different DataFrame?  If that is the expected result, what is the result you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that's the best answer : (Im kinda new to Python too)

let's say that's your original dataframe is df

```
for even, odd in zip(df.iloc[::2], df.iloc[1::2]):
    if even.status!=odd.status:
        #do you append here
```

You should give a runnable df example so we could run our code before posting it to be sure it really works

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it! I tried for an hour before posting and as soon as I posted it clicked

It's a lot simpler than a for loop.

I created a new column called 'MATCH' that has a boolean value of whether or not the new value of 'STATUS' is equal or not to the previous.

Then I just filter by df.STATUS == False

'''python 
df['MATCH'] = df.STATUS.eq(df.STATUS.shift())'''

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
df[df['STATUS'].ne(df['STATUS'].shift().bfill())]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

drop_duplicates won't work because as you go down the list 'STATUS' values are repeated. Something might go from IPRG to WORK back to IPRG, and I want to get both of those breaks

Comment: Edited based on this additional information. Please try the update.

Comment: bfill not is necessary here